# Why wont my HTML5 code work?

Tags: css, html

THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP GUYS, HAVE FIXED IT!! :D
Just wondering why my code wont work? Under the navigation bar my paragraph wont show? Also how would i put my navigation bar all on one line? Sorry if this is really dumb, im new to this!

New updated code that sill wont show the paragraph at the bottom.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
 <title> Home </title> 
 </head>

 <body>

 <img src="Andora ski trip.JPG" alt="View from flat in Andora" height="400" width="100%">


 <h1> Home </h1>

 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="Curriculum vitae.html">Curriculum vitae</a></li>
   <li><a href="literature review.html">Literature review</a></li>
   <li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>

 <p>My name is Jack Hay and this is the first proper website that i have designed. My aim is to show my CV, some coursework that i have done (Literature review), a short self made video and to learn how to use a stylesheet efficiently</p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

css

```
 h1{
  font-family:"calibri", Times, Serif;
  colour: White;
  font-size:50px ;
  padding:0.1px;
  margin:5
 }

 ul
 {
   list-style-type: none;
 }

 ul li
 {
   display: block;
   width: 25%
   float: left
 }
```

Comment: Your code should be *within* the body tag.

Comment: For Navigation bar please show us CSS file

Comment: [Validators](http://validator.nu) are your friend.

Comment: post your css and then we will have a better idea of what is going on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

... your head and body tags at the top were messed up.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title> Curriculum vitae </title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>



<img src="Andora ski trip.JPG" alt="View from flat in Andora" height="400" width="100%">

<h1> Curriculum vitae </h1>



<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Curriculum vitae.html">Curriculum vitae</a></li>
<li><a href="literature review.html">Literature review</a></li>
<li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<p>My name is Jack and this is the first proper website that i have designed. My aim is to show my CV, some coursework that i have done (Literature review), a short self made video and to learn how to use a stylesheet efficiently</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, just tried that and has the same problem?

Comment: What problem is that specifically, there could be few judging by your question and looking at your code.

Comment: Title should be in the head

Comment: The Paragraph tag still wont show anything, i have tried putting it in an article but still no luck :(

Comment: Look at what user3097405 did with the UL and it's LI elements. You had h2, they need to be LI like he did. I missed first time :-(

Comment: ... and I missed the title position :-(

Comment: I have just updated my code at the top and still no luck with the <p> tag, just cant seem to get it to display. Thanks for all your help though guys!

Comment: ... here, have a look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HenriPablo/TKdLv/ all seems to display, next if this does not help do use the w3c validator as previously suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Start by replacing the h2 tags with li tags.  It's not valid html.

To put the nav in one line you would do something like this in your css:

```
ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
 }

ul li
{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the code you have posted there, the paragraph should be showing, it may be that your css is moving the paragraph off screen and/or **setting the text to your background colour**.

You should also move the `<h1>` and `<img>` tags out of the head and put them in the body. The head tags are for giving the browser information, not for containing content for the user.

To display you nav all in one line, you will need to change your nav tags to li (not h2) and then in your css:

```
ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
}

ul li
{
 display: block;
 width: 25%
 float: left
}
```